# Rounding a figure retrieved from html using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rounding

I am having a little problem with rounding numbers which are brought in from html.

For example a value extracted from `<input id="salesValue"> using var salesValue = $("salesValue").val()` would give me a text value.

So if I did something like `var doubleSalesValue = salesValue + salesValue;` , it would return the number as a concatenation instead of summation of the two values.

I could use var `doubleSalesValue = salesValue * 2.0;` which does return the value which is to multiple decimal places. However, if I did want to use the other method, how can I approach the situation.

What methods do you use? I have created a function which I run on each number where I want to restrict the decimal places along with converting the type to **number**

```
function round(number, figure){
    return Number(Number(number).toFixed(figure));
}
```

I have to run Number initially to make sure that the value is converted to type number and has the method `toFixed`, otherwise it would throw an error here. Then I have to round the number again to the number of decimal places as required by the function, and somehow after running the `toFixed` method the number would sometimes turn to a string.

So, I decided to run the `Number` function `Number(number).toFixed(figure)`

Is there anything else or any different paradigm that you follow?

***EDIT: I want to know if what I am doing here is conventional or are there better methods for this in general?***

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round it to 2 decimals you can simply do this:

`var roundedNum = Math.round(parseFloat(originalNum) * 100) / 100;`

Regarding your question:

> and somehow after running the toFixed method the number would sometimes turn to a string.

I suggest next time read the dox a bit better https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed which says:

> **Returns**
>
> A string representation of number that does not use exponential
>   notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The
>   number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with
>   zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If number is
>   greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls
>   Number.prototype.toString() and returns a string in exponential
>   notation.